# How to search for a list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, search

How do I search for a paticular list within a list of lists so specifically:

Say i have a list grid_list that contains many other lists and i want to search through the grid_list to find one of these specifically how could i do this? here is the code that i think should work but 
doesnt:

```
import sys #sys has been imported to take in user input
import random #random has been imported to generate random numbers to store the ants food in in the grid

#grid list is a generated list used to store grid values
grid_list = []
grid_size=0 #grid size is a variable that is assigned a value in function space and used in other functions, has default value of zero
ant_position="" #ants current position in grid used in more than one function
food_location="" #foods position in grid used in more than one function

#function for setting up a grid
def space():

print("please enter the size of the square grid you want")
#grid size is assigned by user input
global grid_size 
grid_size = int(sys.stdin.readline())
#embedded for loops to set up a list that stores grid points
for count in range(0,grid_size):
    x_number= count+1 #x number is the x number of the cell in the grid
    for count in range(0,grid_size):
        y_number= count+1 # y number is the y number of the cell in the grid
        grid_list.append([x_number,y_number,0,0,0]) #this stores a list within a list, so the first two values of the second list represent the co-ordinates of the cell the last three represent pheromone, food location, ant location (both food and ant location take value of one if either are in there)

def locations():

global food_location

food_location_x = (random.randint(1,grid_size)) #gives the x value of the cell the food is stored in
food_location_y = (random.randint(1,grid_size)) #gives the y value of the cell the food is stored in
food_location = [food_location_x,food_location_y,0,0,0] #gives the full location of the food and will use this to in other functions to reference the grid list
for count in range(0,4):
    grid_list[[grid_list.index([food_location])][count]] = [food_location_x,food_location_y,0,1,0]
print(grid_list[grid_list.index(food_location)])
```

this code sets up a list that contains many other lists, (space function) and then changes one of the lists in the list (grid_list) to represent that it contains the food.

However instead of this working i get a value error saying that [2,1,0,0,0] is not in the list or whatever other grid value the code gives (2 and 1 can be replaced by any positive integer in this situation). Can someone please explain to me how i can change this so it searches for it correctly?

Comment: Please correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: FYI, you aren't creating your grid properly, because you're overriding the `count` for-loop variable by using it again for the internal loop. I suggest using informative names, such as `row` and `column`.

Comment: Actually, while horrible to do, the way Python implements loops means that this code actually does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs in this code. The first, previously noted by roippi, is that you are putting `food_location` in a list before searching for it. The second is that you are doing this same thing four times. You are searching for `[x,y,0,0,0]`, replacing it, and then searching for the same `[x,y,0,0,0]` in the list. Since you just replaced that element, it does not exist any more and you get the error you're seeing.

As roippi noted, a better way to get 4 positions to replace would be to use

```
random.sample(grid_list, 4)
```

And modify each of the four lists returned so that the fourth element was 1. random.sample will return the *same* lists that are in the grid_list, so modifying the elements of these lists will modify them in the grid_list as well.

Comment: ok thankyou, now i get the error list indices must be integers not lists?

Comment: ok thankyou very much i figured it out it was because I hadnt taken out square brackets when trying to find the index of the gridlist so it assumed i was searching for a list

Answer (score 1):

One bug I can see:

```
grid_list.index([food_location])
```

You are putting `food_location` into a list.  But `food_location` is *already* a list, so now you have a list within a list.  When you do `grid_list.index(that)`, it tells you that there's no doubly-nested list in `grid_list`.

Honestly it looks like you're doing a really funky method to get a random sampling of `grid_list`.  You should be using `random.choice` or `random.sample` to get one or many random elements out of your collection, respectively.

Comment: i know i did change this and it was the same result that it couldnt find the list and that the value wasnt part of the list. I do not understand why it cant find it?

Answer (score 0):

You're representing a two-dimensional array as a list of lists, and you're trying to search it for an item. You simply can't use `grid_list.index()` for such a search. The items in `grid_list` are your grid's columns, so `grid_list.index(item)` is comparing the item to entire columns, therefore not finding a match.

I recommend defining a function which will do the search you want. Something like:

```
def find_in_grid(grid, item_to_find):
    """search for a given item in a grid

    If found, the indexes (x, y) are returned. Otherwise, returns None.
    """
    for row in range(len(grid)):
        for column in range(len(grid[row])):
            if grid[row][column] == item_to_find:
                return (row, column)
    return None # item not found in the grid
```

Of course, it would be even better to define a simple `Grid` class and give it a `find()` or `index()` method.

Comment: thanks for the input but a bit advanced for me at the moment :L

Comment: Hopefully this might give you some ideas on useful things to learn going forward, and how to write better code as you learn.